# ANTLR4 - A way to skip/stop invokeing events until further notice

Tags: antlr4

Is there a way to notify A Listener to stop invoking events until further notice ?

For example :

Let’s assume a listener for  recurrent structure like SQL SELECT.

`“SELECT  * FROM TABLE_B  b  WHERE b.id IN (SELECT  a.ID FROM TABLE_A  a  WHERE a.ID = 10 )”`

Now I want to send the sub-select to a secondary listener, but without the main listener processing the sub-select tokens?

something in the line of  :

```
void SQLLISTENER::enterSubSelect (SQLParser::SubSelectContext *ctx) override { 
          
         stopProcessingToken() ; //Stop processing main listener 
          SQLLISTENER * listener = new SQLLISTENER ();
          antlr4::tree::ParseTreeWalker::DEFAULT.walk(listener, ctx);

}
void SQLLISTENER::exitSubSelect(SQLParser::SubSelectContext *ctx) override {

        StartProcessingToken(); //Resume processing main listener 
}
```

1. Does ANTLR support this type of skip tokens?
2. Is there a more elegant way to achieve processing of recursive sections ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A listener always fires both enter- and exit-events, for all nodes in the parse tree. You can indeed keep track of how many times a certain `enter` rule is invoked, and base your logic on that. However, this will get cumbersome when the amount of rules becomes large (and the growing amount of checks because of that).

Perhaps better in you case to use a visitor: with a visitor you can decide when you want it to dive into a certain (sub) tree or not. When you decide not to go into a (sub) tree, it will be skipped entirely.